# CakePHP virtual HABTM table/relation, something like fixture

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

first of all I'd like to tell you that you're terrific audience.

I'm making an application where I have model `Foo` with table `Foos`. And I'd like to give Foo another parameter, HABTM parameter, lets say `Bar`. But I'd rather don't create table for `Bar`. Because `Bar` will have like 5 positions on start and in 5 years it will grow to maybe 7 positions or not at all. So I don't see a need to create another table and make CakePHP look into that table with another SELECT. Anyone have an idea this can be achieved ?

One solution I think is making an fixture for `Bars` table and adding only `Bars_Foos` table for real (it won't be big anyway). But I can't find a way to use test fixtures in normal `Controller`

Second solution is to save a JSON or serialized array in `Foo` one field and move logic to model, but I don't know if it is best solution. Something like virtual field.

Real life example:

So I have like `Bikes`. And every `Bike` have its `main_type`. Which is for now `{"MTB","Road","Trekking","City","Downhill"}`. I know that in long time this list would not grow much. Maybe 2 or 5 positions in few years. Still it will relatively short.

(For those who say that there maybe a hundred of specialized bike types. I have another parameter column `specialized_type`)

It needs to be a HABTM relation, but `main_types` table will be very small, so Id like to avoid creating it and find a way for simpler solution.

Because

- It bothers MySQL for such small amount of data
- It complicates MySQL queries
- I have to make additional model for `MainType`
- I have more models to unbind when I don't need most of data and would like use `recursive`
- Insert here anything you'd like...

Comment: So when you say "positions" you mean table rows? It might be easier to understand the why and how, and maybe suggest other solutions that are more appropriate if you'd describe your problem by means of a real world example.

Comment: I had added real life example. Say if it pleases you.

Answer (score 1):

Judging from your real life example, I'd say you're on the wrong track. The queries won't be complicated, CakePHP uses additional queries for HABTM relations, it would be just one additional query which shouldn't be very costly, also it's very easy to sparse it out by using the [containable behaviour](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html). And if you really need to use `recursive` only (for whatever reason), then it's just one single additional model to unbind, that doesn't seem like overkill to me.

This might not be what you wanted to hear, but I really think a proper database solution is better than trying to hack in "virtual data". Also note that fixtures as used in tests, only define data which is written to the database on the fly when running the test, so that would be definitely more costly than using data that already exists in the database.

Maybe you'll get a small performance boost for selects that do not query the main type when using an additional column to store the data, but you'll definitely lose all the flexibility that the RDBMS has to offer, including faster selects using proper indexing, affecting multiple records by updating a single related value, etc. That doesn't sound like a good trade-off to me. Think about it, how would you select all `Downhill` `Tracking` bikes when this information is stored as a string in a single column? You would probably end up using ugly `LIKE` selects.

Now wait, there's a [`SET` data type](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/set.html) in MySQL hat can hold multiple values. Right, and it looks easier and less complex. Right, but in the background it isn't, while using a complex looking join-query can be pretty fast using proper indexing, the query for the `SET` type will have to scan every single row since the data stored in the column cannot be indexed appropriately in order to make more specific selects.

In the end it probably depends on your data, so I'd suggest testing both methods in your specific environment and see how they compare under workload.